# Pass an array through a function

Tags: c++, arrays, mean

I'm trying to pass a simple array through a function to compute the mean.

```
int main()
{
    int n = 0; // the number of grades in the array
    double *a; // the array of grades

    cout << "Enter number of scores: ";
    cin >> n;

    a = new double[n]; // the array of grades set 
                       // to the size of the user input

    cout << "Enter scores separated by blanks: ";
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    computeMean(a, n);
}

double computeMean (double values[ ], int n)
{
    double sum;
    double mean = 0;
    mean += (*values/n);
    return mean;
}
```

Right now the code is only taking the mean of the last number that was inputted.

Comment: If this is a homework question, you should mark it as such

Comment: @Mike yes it was the first, I misspoke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no loop in your function. It should be something like:

```
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
  sum += values[i];

return sum / n;
```

I'm surprised your current version only takes the *last* number, it should only take the *first* number, since `*values` is the same as `values[0]`.

A better solution uses idiomatic C++:

```
return std::accumulate(values, values + n, 0.0) / n;
```

Comment: Except you should call it `sum` instead of `mean` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Note that passing the integer `0` causes each value and the final result to be rounded off.

Comment: Oh, good point - let me edit that! `accumulate` is a curious specimen... :-)

Comment: Building on @Potatoswatter's comment, I guess passing `0.0` means that all the math is done in `double` precision, and that if you just want `float` precision you'd need either `0.0f` or `float(0)`? (I'd recommend the second form for legibility.)

Comment: @Mike: The type of the third argument in `accumulate` determines the result type. Leave it at double and assign it to a float when you're done; there's no harm for you, and you might as well take advantage of the doubles you already have. Sorting the array first might be an idea, too.

Comment: It depends on what you want. If double math is too slow, then forcing float math is the way to go. Bear in mind that on a lot of architectures, double math is in software while float math is in hardware and executes additions and/or multiplications in a single cycle (which is why multiplying by `(1.0 / n)` instead of dividing by `n` is faster if `n` is constant). But what would sorting accomplish?

Comment: @Mike: Similarly, on lots of platforms floats get promoted to doubles in any case for computations - it all depends :-) Sorting and adding from the smallest to the largest may improve the accuracy of the result, especially if your values are of vastly different scales.

Comment: C promotes floats to doubles implicitly because a lot of `<math.h>` is uses doubles. Hopefully scores aren't so widely dispersed in magnitude as to require sorting to preserve accuracy.

Comment: C has definite promotion rules, so that wasn't what I meant. But if you look at the machine code produced for your standard desktop hardware, you will probably see that all your floats are treated the same as doubles -- but double-check to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

`std::accumulate` should do the trick.

```
#include <numeric>

double computeMean (double values[ ], int n) {
    return std::accumulate( values, values + n, 0. ) / n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a homework question?

You nead to step through all of the values in your array. You're currently outputting the first number in the array divided by the number of items.